# hey i am trying to use local storage in the new app router in next js 13 but app breaks every time i use it though i applied use client on top

Tags: javascript, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

this is redux slice where i want to use the local storage for adding products to cart but it's not working on next js 13 app i used use client method also

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

const initialState = {
  cartState: false,
  cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cart")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    : [], // Let Suppose Database
  cartTotalAmount: 0,
  cartTotalQantity: 0,
};

const CartSlice = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: "cart",
  reducers: {
    setOpenCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cartState = action.payload.cartState;
    },
    setCloseCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cartState = action.payload.cartState;
    },
    setAddItemToCart: (state, action) => {
      const itemIndex = state.cartItems.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        state.cartItems[itemIndex].cartQuantity += 1;

        toast.success(`Item QTY Increased`);
      } else {
        const temp = { ...action.payload, cartQuantity: 1 };
        state.cartItems.push(temp);

        toast.success(`${action.payload.title} added to Cart`);
      }

      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state.cartItems));
    },

    setRemoveItemFromCart: (state, action) => {
      const removeItem = state.cartItems.filter(
        (item) => item.id !== action.payload.id
      );

      state.cartItems = removeItem;
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state.cartItems));

      toast.success(`${action.payload.title} Removed From Cart`);
    },

    setIncreaseItemQTY: (state, action) => {
      const itemIndex = state.cartItems.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        state.cartItems[itemIndex].cartQuantity += 1;

        toast.success(`Item QTY Increased`);
      }
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state.cartItems));
    },

    setDecreaseItemQTY: (state, action) => {
      const itemIndex = state.cartItems.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (state.cartItems[itemIndex].cartQuantity > 1) {
        state.cartItems[itemIndex].cartQuantity -= 1;

        toast.success(`Item QTY Decreased`);
      }
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state.cartItems));
    },

    setClearCartItems: (state, action) => {
      state.cartItems = [];
      toast.success(`Cart Cleared`);
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state.cartItems));
    },

    setGetTotals: (state, action) => {
      let { totalAmount, totalQTY } = state.cartItems.reduce((cartTotal, cartItem)=> {
        const { price, cartQuantity } = cartItem;
        const totalPrice = price * cartQuantity;

        cartTotal.totalAmount += totalPrice;
        cartTotal.totalQTY += cartQuantity;

        return cartTotal;
      }, {
        totalAmount: 0,
        totalQTY: 0,
      });

      state.cartTotalAmount = totalAmount;
      state.cartTotalQantity = totalQTY;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setOpenCart,
  setCloseCart,
  setAddItemToCart,
  setRemoveItemFromCart,
  setIncreaseItemQTY,
  setDecreaseItemQTY,
  setClearCartItems,
  setGetTotals
} = CartSlice.actions;

export const selectCartState = (state) => state.cart.cartState;
export const selectCartItems = (state) => state.cart.cartItems;

export const selectTotalAmount = (state) => state.cart.cartTotalAmount;
export const selectTotalQTY = (state) => state.cart.cartTotalQantity;

export default CartSlice.reducer;
```

this is redux slice where i want to use the local storage for adding products to cart but it's not working on next.js 13 app i used use client method also  how dcan i use local storage api

Answer (score 0):

Even a component with `use client` will still be rendered on the server for the first page load. You will have to add `if (typeof window !== "undefined")` checks to everything that is not available on the server.

Also, make sure that on the server, your store never changes - because if you have it as a `export const store =`-type variable, server-side, that store will be shared between *all* requests that are SSRed, so if you would add data in there, that data would get mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Check [zustand with persist middleware](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data)

create a store

persist store with options `{ name: 'name-in-local-storage', skipHydration: true }`

rehydrate your client components where you use your store

```
 useEffect(() => {
    useMyStore.persist.rehydrate()
  }, [])
```